# How to work with objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

How to work with object, if I want...

```
var object = { 'title': value };

alert( object[ /* Whatever */ ] ); // Should return 'title' NOT value
```

Thanks.

Comment: @All OP confirmed in a comment on a now-deleted answer that he/she really wants the string "title" -- the **name** of the property.

Comment: read this: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `for...in` loop to enumerate an object's keys, like this:

```
for(var key in object) {
  alert(key);  //to get the key's value, use object[key]
}
```

To be safe, in case someone messed with the object prototype, use [`.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) like this:

```
for(var key in object) {
  if(object.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    alert(key);
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 Might be worth mentioning `hasOwnProperty`. :-) And possibly ECMAScript 5's `Object.keys`.

Comment: Nick, I must say... You are the Javascript God! Thank you!

Comment: @Marry - you're kind :) there are *lots* of brilliant people here, many much smarter than I...and some of the top JavaScript guys aren't here at all ;)

Comment: here is some Scriptures for you - https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JavaScript :-)